# Bot receiving duplicate card click events

Tags: c#, google-hangouts

I am using the following libraries to connect a bot to a Google Pub/Sub endpoint to perform a simple reply to a card click event.

`Google.Apis.HangoutsChat.v1 1.34.0.1233`

`Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1 1.0.0-beta18`

When I construct my card, everything looks normal in the UI, including the button that is supposed to raise the event.

The topic and subscription contain the default settings, following the guide [here](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/how-tos/pub-sub)

I found the following information from the Google documentation about retries [here](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/how-tos/bots-develop#retry)

> Responding synchronously
>
> A bot can respond to an event synchronously by returning a
>   JSON-formatted message payload in the HTTP response. The deadline for
>   a synchronous response is 30 seconds.
>
> A synchronous response from a bot is always posted in the thread that
>   generated the event to the bot.

After clicking the button, my subscriber receives *3 duplicate events*. The events have the correct response with all of the right metadata, but are exact duplicates of each other, including the id of the message itself.

I don't feel there is a necessarily large delay in the response of the bot (it should happen in <1 second for this test), so I am not sure why these messages are being duplicated.

I've also tried setting the thread id for the card when responding (via the `Thread` property itself, or the `ThreadKey` property), but I always seem to get a new thread id when I post a message.

```
var cardMessage = MessageSender.Spaces.Messages.Create(new Message()
{
    Space = new Space()
    {
        Name = inReplyToThisMessage.Space.Name
    },
    Thread = new Thread()
    {
        Name = inReplyToThisMessage.Thread.Name
    },
    Cards = new List<Card>()
    {
        card
    },
}, inReplyToThisMessage.Space.Name);

var sendCardResult = await cardMessage.ExecuteAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
//Thread id of sendCardResult does not match inReplyToThisMessage.Thread.Name no matter what
```

Interestingly enough, trying to create a new message in response to the click event causes the bot to display a "Unable to connect to bot. Try again later", but displays 3 new messages. Also, when specifying an arbitrary thread key, this key is never echoed back in the bot's response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug has finally been fixed by Google.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are returning the main *event* method properly. What looks to be happening is that you are making an asynchronous call to the chat, but then the chat is looking for a response from the actual event method itself. Google will traditionally try *three* times before giving up (even if it doesn't take thirty seconds)

If you are indeed returning the event call correctly after you made your api request, then there is something in your code that is causing the Google Bot to think it is not getting a response, so it tries three times. Since the issue could be multi-faceted I would need to look at how you are accepting and returning the click response.

Comment: I'm not sure what else there is to do to respond. Using `SubscriberClient.Reply.AckOk` is used to let the Pub/Sub infrastructure know that the message was consumed successfully (there's only two options -- AckOk, or NAck). There isn't anything documented on the Chat API to suggest something additional needs to be done though. According to the docs, https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/images/pubsub-arch.png shows that a direct HTTP call to the Hangouts Chat API is sufficient after ack'ing the message.

Comment: The documentation and API for chat is still relatively new so all they don't cover all of their bases. Try setting a method where on the duplicate messages (events triggering the bot) you immediately return them. You can do this by comparing the eventTime with the original time of the first message, if it's the same return (its a duplicate). This should work if Google is triggering your bot multiple times.

Comment: Actually I did that. I said if the response is CARD_CLICKED, return immediately. I still get duplicates. I've opened a bug on Google's end, hopefully someone will take a look at it.

Comment: Are there multiple events being registered with the bot?

Comment: No, only one topic and subscription, set up just like described in their documentation. One bot as well.

Comment: What happens when you use Update Message instead of Create Message? Does it update the card 3 times in a row?

Comment: CREATE_MESSAGE actually displays an error on the bot, UPDATE_MESSAGE causes the duplicates. It appears the docs say that UPDATE_MESSAGE is preferred for card updates responding to click events

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176745/discussion-between-bryan-crosby-and-logan-cundiff).

Comment: Greetings @BryanCrosby I have the exact same issue, have you been able to solve your problem? Note this only occurs for CARD_CLICKED events, not MESSAGE events. Personally, I return an empty HTTP 200 Response to Pub/Sub  (configured in Push mode), before handling the event, but I receive the request 3 times regardless.

Comment: @Konrad I opened a bug tracker issue on this about 4 months ago. It is still "under investigation". I've been able to work around it by just saving off the message id and ignoring any subsequent requests. Not ideal, but it works until they can fix it.

Comment: Hi @BryanCrosby, thanks, I added a comment to your issue in their issue tracker. What are you using as the message ID? Personally, I used the same method, checking if the full request body had already been handled.

Comment: I am using the literal messageId from Hangouts Chat, which seems good enough for now, e.g. /spaces/xyz/messages/abc.123 Hashing the whole request body could work to

Comment: While the issue has been solved technically thanks to this workaround, Chat displays the following error under tapped buttons: "Unable to contact {bot_name}. Try again later." Do you have this too? @BryanCrosby

Comment: @Konrad I always would get that error if I failed to update the exact card or message that originally invoked the click event. It seems that you must perform an update to that card or message to avoid getting that error message.

Comment: So I need to make a specific card update call to avoid this, since I am not sending a response directly (I can't, I'm using Pub/Sub)?